# Certificate Pinning - Refresh Pinned Certificate Mechanism

Tags: ssl, cryptography, certificate, certificate-pinning

I am working on a client architecture where we plan to pin our clients against our servers. My server leaf certificates can change throughout our product lifecycle, which is why we would need a refresh mechanism to support our older released clients with embedded certs.

Here are two approaches I have planned:

Plan on using a set of backup public/private key pair, private being kept with us in a HSM. public key is embedded in client.

**approach 1 :**

*On leaf expiry*

Issue a leaf certificate pinset which could be downloaded on public internet.

On Client, download this leaf pinset with pinned root certificate.

if download successful, use this new leaf pinset and pin it for all subsequent HTTP calls.

*If Leaf + Root expired*

If for some reason, root also expired, or root was changed to a new provider.

On client, download leaf pinset with root certificate -> Failure because root expired.

Refresh root, download new root pinset signed by backup private key. This is an unpinned call.

After downloading verify signature using client embedded backup public key.

If successful, use this root pinset, pin it to download leaf.
Use downloaded leaf and pin it for subsequent http calls.

**approach 2 :**

*Make above approach more streamlined and avoid root pinset altogether.*

Sign leaf pinset with backup private key and keep pinset which could be downloaded in public internet.

while refresh downloading it on client, download using unpinned call.

After download successful, verify using backup pub key and use it for all http calls.

My question with above 2 approaches is, does **approach 2** leave any room for security exploit, overall I feel like having to deal with less number of artefacts on client is the way to go, but I do not want to compromise security in anyway.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Pinning works when keys rarely change, that's why you often want to pin root certificates. You only need to change the root certificate if you've had a key compromise.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further ? Why is it a bad practice to pin leaf, if we do have a mechanism to rotate leaf whenever it changes. Pardon my understanding on this subject but if someone tried to impersonate my domain by signing his domain using same root, straight up root pinning would cause an issue in this regard right ?

Comment: While offtopic here at this stage since it is not very programming related, your setup seems  a lot like what happens in DNSSEC with the split between KSK and ZSK and how KSK are rotated. You may want to look at it to maybe help you in your case. The recent root key rotation could be used as a guide.

Comment: *...if someone tried to impersonate my domain by signing his domain using same root...* That's just not how it works. You probably need to step back and explain what you're trying to accomplish with all this pinning. Pinning is about trust: you decide which certificate(s) to trust. Why would you need to change your root certificate? If you cannot protect your private keys then pinning won't save you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion, root keys may change if we change our issuing CA to a different provider. Furthermore, use case of application is long term. There is a possibility the root certificate will simply expire within timeline. In that case, rotating root cert is also a possibility. It's very much possible neither of these two would ever be encountered. I'm just trying to list down all possibilities where root needs to be rotated.

Comment: Following wiki's definition of http pinning 

At least one backup key must be pinned, in case the current pinned key needs to be replaced. The HPKP is not valid without this backup key (a backup key is defined as a public key not present in the current certificate chain).